# PHP URI values showing up as undefined

Tags: php, variables, uri, undefined

What I want to do is echo the value of $test on my page, through the uri. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Code:

```
<?php echo $test?>
```

URL:

localhost/testMap/test.php?test=hallo

Comment: You can call param by $_GET['test']

Comment: Try <?php echo $_REQUEST['test']; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of url with a get, and store it in the variable `$test` and then echo that out.

```
$test = $_GET['test'];
```

Comment: I didn't know you had to use $_GET in this context too! Lesson learned!